# How can I make the Hard difficulty harder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want Hard mode to be more difficult. I want the mobs to be tankier (more health points) and hit harder (do more damage). How can I do that?

Comment: There's also "ultra hard core", where you only regenerate health through potions and golden apples, nothing else. And hardcore alone already adds a lot of challenge, because you have to be much more careful not to die if that means losing the world.

Comment: @FabianRöling Since 1.14 UHC got much easier with suspicious stew of regeneration, made with oxy daisy, bowl, red and brown mushroom.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably with status effects. Put a repeating command block chain down somewhere with these commands:

```
effect give @e[type=!player] strength 1 0 true
effect give @e[type=!player] resistance 1 0 true
```

You can increase the `0` to increase the effect. But note that with `4` or more as the value for the resistance effect amplifier, all mobs become invincible (except for void damage and commands).

Comment: Do i have to add something in this command block? Like in "player" i'd have to put the name of the mob that i want to change?

Comment: No, the commands work exactly like they are. "`@e[type=!player]`" means "everything except players".

Comment: I'm new here and it says that i shouldn't add comments like "thanks" but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the mobs stats by doing this commands. Be sure you have cheats on so you can do the commands. Cheats can be accessed in the settings.Do:

/effect @a minecraft:resistance 999999 (any number between 0-4) true , then:

/effect @a minecraft:strength 999999 (any number between 0-4) true

Lastly, do:

/effect @p clear

and there you go, the monsters got more damage and more health. They didn't really got more health, but got more resistance, reducing damage, acting like a health boost. Just be sure you don't give them too much strength, as that may cause them to kill you in a few hits, or too much resistance, because then very high damage may seem just like a snowball for them.
For some odd reason, sometimes, the timer(999999) will last for approximately 25:56 minutes, so you may need to use the same commands multiple times when the effect will go away. If the commands do not work(e.g./effect @a minecraft:strength/resistance 999999 (any number you want) true), after the @a do [type=mob] without space between the @a and the [type=mob].

Hope it helps you and if it does, good luck in your journey with the Ultra Hardcore difficulty.

Remember that it won't work on bosses that aren't alive, so if you want them to get better too, do the commands you did on the mobs. Be sure to do /gamemode c first before using the commands on the bosses, as if not you risk to be harmed and even die if you do the commands while in the fight. Also remember to do /effect @p clear after doing the commands on the bosses.